# Работа с классами и sfml

Tags: c++, функции, sfml, параметры

Имеется класс button, который будет являться кнопкой в приложении. Используется вот так:

```
button playButton;
playButton.create(20, 20, 120, 30, "123, 123, 123, "some", "value");
window->draw(playButton);
```

Сам же класс таков:

```
class button {
    public:

        void create(int x, int y, int width, int height, char color, char name, char text)
        {
            sf::CircleShape name(50);
            name.setFillColor(sf::Color(color));
            name.setOutlineThickness(10);
            name.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(250, 150, 100));
            name.setPosition(x, y);
        }

    private:
};
```

Однако компилятор при попытке собрать программу плюётся, выдавая:

```
[Error] declaration of 'sf::CircleShape name' shadows a parameter
```

Никак не могу понять в чём дело. Если использовать вот так, не пытаясь засунуть в класс, а сунув в основной поток то всё нормально работает:

```
sf::CircleShape name(50);
name.setFillColor(sf::Color(123,123,123));
name.setOutlineThickness(10);
name.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(250, 150, 100));
name.setPosition(20, 20);
window->draw(name);
```

Comment: У Вас есть аргумент функции с именем `name` и Вы объявляете локальную переменную с именем `name`.

Comment: @kff выходит, объявлять локальную переменную в таком случае нет необходимости?

Comment: Тяжёлый случай...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом определении функции- члена класса

```
void create(int x, int y, int width, int height, char color, char name, char text)
                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^   
{
    sf::CircleShape name(50);
                    ^^^^^^^^
```

объявление локальной переменной с типом `sf::CircleShape` скрывает одноименное объявление параметра с типом `char`, о чем вам компилятор и сообщает, так как такое определении функции не имеет смысла.

Помимо этого вы вызываете функцию, передавая в нее в качестве аргументов строковые литералы `"some"` и `"value"`

```
playButton.create(20, 20, 120, 30, "123, 123, 123, "some", "value");
                                                   ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^
```

которые в общем случае, если соответствующие параметры не имеют ссылочные типы, неявно преобразуются в указатели на свои первые символы  и имеют тип `const char *`, но никак не `char`. То есть компилятор еще должен выдать диагностическое сообщение о неправильных типах аргументов для этих параметров, то есть что он не может преобразовать, например, тип `const char[5]` в тип `char` для аргумента  `"some"`.

Кроме того обратите внимание, что локальная переменная `name`, объявленная в теле функции, станет не действительной после завершения работы функции. То есть время ее жизни - это тело функции во время его выполнения.

Comment: У ТС ещё и несоответствие типов при вызове этой чертовщины - `const char*` вместо `char`...

Comment: @kff  Спасибо, я отметил это несоответствие в своем ответе.